# Google Play: Registering as two people

Tags: android, google-play, registration

Is it possible to register as two people rather than an individual without setting up a company? I know you can register as an individual or a company, but I want to cooperate with a friend to make an app. Is that possible if we want to publish an app onto Google Play? If not, is there some other place we could do this, like Apple App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different access levels on the Google Play Developer Console: **"Account owner"** and **"Users"**.

The account owner is the first account registered on the Google Play Developer Console. Account owners can add users, manage individual permissions, and remove user access. Users don't need to pay the $25 Developer registration fee to access the Developer Console.

Here's a summary of how account owners and users can use the Google Play Developer Console: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691.

Comment: I see! So one of us will be the owner and the other will be the user, but joint operation would be invalid without a company. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!